# Installing Facebook Connect for PhoneGap Build - is this right?

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Is my method correct? I'm getting these errors:

```
Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly

CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly

FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.
```

1. I have my Facebook app set up. I've been signing into it using Connect for a couple of years now via the php sdk. For Phonegap Build (not manual), am I also supposed to download a javascript sdk from Facebook, or do I just follow the steps below?
2. added this to my **config.xml**  :

   ```
     <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
     <param name="APP_ID" value="blah_app_id" />
     <param name="APP_NAME" value="blah_app_name" />
     </gap:plugin>
   ```
3. Went to https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/

and downloaded

```
cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js
facebook-js-sdk.js
```

and placed them in the root of my project - same place as my index.html

1. Copied the code from between the body tags at index.html from the example at https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/tree/master/example/Simple, and placed it into my Phonegap Build's index.html, in order to test.
2. zip and upload to PGB as normal

What step/s am I missing or screwing up?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: No, don't download _cordova facebook plugin_ and _facebook js sdk_ . It will be added/appended while app built in cloud.

Comment: Thanks jeek. How does it access the facebook sdk for the web-app version of the app then?

Comment: If you mention like:  <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<!-- facebook js sdk -->
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>

Comment: But those files aren't on my website. I get how PG Build adds them when they make they native versions, but don't I need to upload them to my site for the web-app version?